# Use of Rxjs functions with two observables

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I want to perform some action with one observable say add 20 to one of its property

```
const mainObservable = of({id:1, count: 20});
const example = mainObservable.pipe(
    map(val=> { val.count+20; return val;})
);
```

Then I need to check a condition of other observable and if it is true, then perform further operations like adding 40 to one of the property of first observable

**Combined code:**

```
const mainObservable = of({id:1, count: 20});

const otherObservable = of([10,20]);
const example = mainObservable.pipe(
  map(val=> { val.count+20; return val;}),
  switchMap(outerVal => otherObservable.pipe(map(val=>{
     console.log(outerVal);
     return val.length > 0;
     }))),
 // map(val=> {val.count+ 40, return val})

);
```

Here, if condition of otherObservable is true then I need to added 40 into count and at last in the subscribe I should get the actual object of first observable.

Could anybody please help me with this along with explanation? Commented code should be introduced in order to achieve the requirement so that

example observable should emit object of from first observable

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-fraqgl?devtoolsheight=60)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're looking for operators `combineLatest` or `withLatestFrom` depending on what logic you want. For example with `withLatestFrom` you could do this like this:

```
const example = mainObservable.pipe(
  map(val => {
    val.count + 20;
    return val;
  }),
  withLatestFrom(otherObservable),
  map(([first, second]) => {
     console.log(first, second);
     return second.length > 0;
  }),
);
```

Only when `mainObservable` emits it takes the latest value from `otherObservable` that you can use to do whatever you want.

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jnmehl?file=index.ts

Comment: But still subscribe on example returns me true, it should return that object which is modified

Comment: Then just `return first;` instead of `return second.length > 0`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated stackblitz with your expected result.

```
const example = mainObservable.pipe(
  map(val=> { val.count += 20; return val;}),
      switchMap(outerVal => otherObservable.pipe(map(val=>{
         if(val.length){
           outerVal.count += 40;
         } 
         return outerVal;
         })
      )),
     // map(val=> {val.count+ 40, return val})

    );
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tf8r4p